# Is there a way to use offline Gmail with Firefox 4+

Tags: firefox, gmail

I want to use offline Gmail with the new versions of Firefox (like 8). Is there a way to get it working? Some way of hacking Gears' addon and changing its max version to make it compatible with the versions? Or someway of using Chrome addon in Firefox? Or any other way?

Comment: This is a programming site.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there’s no way to use the Gmail offline app on browsers other than Google Chrome. Google has announced they will be releasing the Chrome apps as plugins by the end of December 2011.